# How to resolve issue on assigning values to LINQ variable with Double ToDouble Method

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have this line of code which works well

```
itemPrice = g.Sum<st_groupitem>((st_groupitem x) => x.item_price * x.item_qty) / g.Sum<st_groupitem>((st_groupitem x) => x.item_qty)
```

I want to round off the **x.item_price * x.item_qty** to 2 decimal numbers. So I changed the code to:

```
itemPrice = g.Sum<st_groupitem>((st_groupitem x) => Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:0.0#}", Convert.ToDecimal(x.item_price * x.item_qty)))) / g.Sum<st_groupitem>((st_groupitem x) => x.item_qty)
```

But when I run the program, I encounter the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double ToDouble(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Note: Given values such as price and quantity are in Double data type.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: .NET Framework or Core? Which version of Entity Framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this would be to use Math.Round on the result, rather than attempting to inline it within the LINQ.

Also, note that in my sample code below I have used decimal rather than double. When dealing with money you should always use decimal to prevent loss of precision when performing math operations.

HTH

The modification to your original line of code would look like this:

```
Math.Round(g.Sum<st_groupitem>((st_groupitem x) => x.item_price * x.item_qty) / g.Sum<st_groupitem>((st_groupitem x) => x.item_qty), 2)
```

And, here is sample code with a test:

```
[TestClass]
public class RoundingTest
{
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Unit")]
    public void GivenTwoItems_WhenAskingToRound_ThenItShouldReturnCorrectValue()
    {
        // arrange
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Price = 10.123m, Quantity = 10 },
            new Item { Price = 20.123m, Quantity = 20 }
        };

        // act
        decimal actual = Math.Round(items.Sum(x => x.Price * x.Quantity) / items.Sum(x => x.Quantity), 2);

        // assert
        actual.Should().Be(16.79m);
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```